# What does this schematic symbol containing one zener diode and four other diodes mean?

Tags: schematics, components

I'm trying to understand what the following symbol is for. It's found in [this schematic](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/ST/STM32-H103/resources/STM32-H103-sch.gif).

[image: unknown schematic symbol]

Comment: I suspect it's a voltage regulator of some sort?

Comment: I think I saw that used in [this circuit](http://xkcd.com/730/)

Comment: What it means is the person who drew that schematic is terrible at drawing readable schematic symbols.

Comment: @Fake Name Hehe! I guess he works for ST Microelectronics. :)

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk - I think you mean Olimex (They're the people who drew that schematic, and yes, their schematics are pretty much universally horrible).

Comment: @Fake Name Hehe, well at least I'm learning something from it.

Comment: I'd say this is a component or collection/cluster of components/symbols, not a symbol in and of itself. /librarian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This device is a [transient voltage suppressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_voltage_suppressor) for USB D+ and D- signals. It protects the device from static voltages that may develop when inserting or removing USB devices to connectors.

The four diodes (on side) act as clamping diodes that conduct to suppress ESD.

This or similar device can be found in this Semtech [catalog](http://www.semtech.com/images/mediacenter/collateral/TVS-SG.pdf)

Comment: Awesome, that's really clever, I didn't think of ESD at all.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like electrostatic discharge (ESD) protection on a USB port.  Any port that a user can touch should have protection against finger zaps frying the chip connected to it.

Have a look at the datasheet for TI TPD2E001 to get an idea what the specs might be.

http://www.ti.com/product/TPD2E001

Answer (score 2):

it is 5 symbols enclosed in one device.  4 normal diodes in a bridge configuration with a zener diode in the middle for simple regulation.

Comment: I don't think it's for regulation; more probably over-voltage or ESD protection of some interconnection.

Comment: Regardless, it's still 4 diodes in bridge configuration with a Zener in the middle.

Comment: I was going to say, "balanced modulator".  I'm glad you guys saved me the embarrassment.  I'm going with the USB answers.  The "pass-through" design supports that notion.